# SQL database re-Indexing script

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2014

What is happening when running below script against SQL Server databases.

My script:

```
set arithabort on
set quoted_identifier on    

use TestDB

declare objcur cursor for
    select name
    from sysobjects
    where type = 'u'
    order by name    

declare @obj sysname    

open objcur   
fetch next from objcur into @obj    

while (@@fetch_status = 0)
begin
    dbcc dbreindex( @obj ) WITH NO_INFOMSGS   

    fetch next from objcur into @obj
end   

deallocate objcur
```

Comment: I'd recommend using the *more focused* `sys.tables` catalog view to get table information - instead of relying on the `sys.objects` and having to remember all those not always very intuitive `type` values for all objects.....

Comment: @marc_s : Thanks for the feedback, Is there any best rebuild indexing script?

Comment: Yes - the great scripts by [Ola Hallengren](https://ola.hallengren.com/) which @scsimon mentioned are the "de facto" standard for this - highly recommended

Answer (score 2):

You are

- Setting ARITHABORT on, which terminates a query when an overflow occurs. By default, this is ON so is likely redundant
- Setting QUOTED_IDENTIFIER on, which tells SQL Server to follow ISO standards about quotation marks. i.e. allows you to use double quotes to delimit identifiers and forcing you to use single quotes for literal strings. This must be on when you are changing indexes on certain types of columns, like computed columns, indexed views, etc. On is the default.
- Creating a cursor (loop) for all tables
- Looping over each table and rebuilding each index, for each table

This isn't a great idea because you have zero thresholds for starters. This means you will rebuild every index regardless if it's fragmented or not, and regardless of the number of pages for this index. So, if you created an fresh index on a fresh table and ran this command, it'd rebuild it. Also, this is an off line operation. So, a shared lock is held for non-clustered indexes for the entire duration of the rebuild which prevents any modifications to the table...

I'd look into using [Ola's scripts](https://ola.hallengren.com/). They are far superior. Then i'd read up on the myths and misconceptions of fragmentation from [Brent Ozar](https://www.brentozar.com/archive/2012/08/sql-server-index-fragmentation/) and again [in this post](https://www.brentozar.com/archive/2016/01/should-i-worry-about-index-fragmentation/).

Comment: Thanks for the review , Please suggest best script to rebuild index of a database

Comment: I did... https://ola.hallengren.com/sql-server-index-and-statistics-maintenance.html

Answer (score 2):

You can use below statement for rebuilding all indexes.

```
Exec sp_msforeachtable 'ALTER INDEX ALL ON ? REBUILD'
```